# pagination on ajax populated table (Over api)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, pagination

I'm trying to have my table which is being populated via an ajax api call paginated.

I've tried a few basic html paginations however these wont work as the data is loaded in afterwards.

I've looked into using the kaminari gem also. Which won't work as its needing to be done in the controller?

How can i achieve pagination on my table if no data is loaded beforehand? (i've looked at datatables but got confused)

Thanks
Sam

**Edit missed code!**

Heres the api.

```
var sortTable = function() {

  $("#tableid tbody tr").detach().sort(function(a, b) {

    var dataA = $(a).find("td:eq(3)").text().trim();

    var dataB = $(b).find("td:eq(3)").text().trim();

    return parseFloat(dataA.substring(1)) - parseFloat(dataB.substring(

      1));

    }).appendTo('#tableid');

  };

  var contentType ="application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";

  if(window.XDomainRequest) contentType = "text/plain";


  $.ajax({
    beforeSend: function (xhr){
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
    },
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: 'REMOVED SENSITIVE URL',
    success: function(json) {
      //var json = $.parseJSON(data);
      for (var i = 0; i < json.TicketGroups.length; i++) {
        var section = json.TicketGroups[i].TicketTypeName;
        var tid = json.TicketGroups[i].Id.slice(1);
        var no = json.TicketGroups[i].QtyOptions.slice(-1)[0];
        var row = json.TicketGroups[i].Row;
        var price = json.TicketGroups[i].Price;
        var notes = json.TicketGroups[i].notes;
        var button =
        "<a class='btn btn-info' data-url='SENSITIVEURLREMOVED'>Buy Now</a>";
        $("#tableid").append("<tr><td><img id='theImg' src='/assets/logo.png'/></td><td><b>" + section +
        "</b></td><td><b>" + no + "</b></td><td><b>£" + price + "</b></td><td><b>N/A</b></td><td><b>£" + price +"</b></td><td><b>" + button + "</b></td></tr>");
        $("#tableid").find(".btn.btn-info").click(function() {
          location.href = $(this).attr("data-url");
        });
      }
      sortTable();
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
```

Comment: What is the difference between "populating the table via ajax" and loading a table from the backend via ajax? Those are exactly the same things, aren't they?

Comment: haha im not sure, All of the ajax calls are apis, And are just append to the tables

Comment: So this is not your api but an external one, right? How do you populate the table first time now? (show the code please!)

Comment: Will add the code now,

Comment: @MichalSzyndel Added code, (theres multiple files that push too the same table however they all look relatively the same

Comment: I still don't know if this API is yours or external?

Comment: ITs external, Sorry, should have made this clear!

Comment: Ok, so looking at your code when you want to load a new page you should just remove all the `tr` lines from the `#tableid` and do an ajax call again, this time to the next page of results (it's probably provided somewhere in API response)

Comment: What i ideally want is after the `#tableid` hits 25 rows, Split across another page, However one api may only have 2 results whereas the other api may have 50 results

Comment: @MichalSzyndel I've tried a few of the paginations on codepen and none worked. the data would load rahter than splitting, and then as soona s i tried to use the pagination it would remove all rows